# Error in the program with the private constructor

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, private

**Even though I've never called function 'Bike::Bike(Bike *)' what is causing the error?**

**Error** : Could not find a match for 'Bike::Bike(Bike *)'

---

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class Bike
{
    Bike()
    {
        cout<<"\nIn Bike const.";
    }

    public: static Bike * getBike();
};

Bike * Bike :: getBike()
{
    cout<<"\nIn getBike";
    return new Bike();
}

void main()
{
    Bike b = Bike::getBike();
}
```

Comment: <iostream.h>? that's a bit old compiler

Comment: `void main` is not legal C++, singletons are an antipattern, and you are leaking a bit of memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to convert from `Bike*` to non-scalar type `Bike`

But `getBike()` returns a pointer to `Bike`

So

```
Bike *b = Bike::getBike();
     ^ use pointer
```

Looks like you're using some decade old compiler may be Turbo C++

`void main` is not legal C++ use `int main`

Also, make sure you delete all memory allocated by `new`

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by **non-scalar** type.

Comment: @ShreyasAgarkar Well, I suggest you to please get a good C++ book and of course a good compiler. In simple terms, C++ objects can be either scalar (e.g. integers and pointers) or non-scalar (e.g. arrays and classes). Scalars are primitive objects which contain a single value and are not composed of other C++ objects.

Comment: about scalar and non-scalar type - check here..http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1995/N0774.pdf